# Input button changes on refresh and only works in one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have an input button which performs a certain function when pressed. When the page first loads, the button looks like the first image - yellow button. When it looks like this, nothing happens when I press the button.

When I refresh the page a couple of times, it changes into the the 2nd image where the button looks silver. This time, when I press the button; it works.

Take note that there is no changes in code between these 2 images. I don't understand 2 things. 1 is why the button image changes. 2 is why does the button not work when it is yellow ? Please advice what is wrong cos I want the final output to be a working yellow button. Thanks.

Image1

[image]

Image2

[image]

The input is declared as follows:

```
$.getJSON("http://s.mx/public/user/listunpaidbills/",function(data){
        //Loop for each element on the data
        $.each(data,function(elem){
            var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
            identity.push(data[elem].id); 
            //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
            $("<h1/>",{
                text:data[elem].reference
            }).appendTo(wrap);   
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Account: "+ data[elem].account
            }).appendTo(wrap);        
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"ID: "+ data[elem].id
            }).appendTo(wrap);

            $("<input type='submit' value='Paid' class='myinput'>",{//input declared here
                text:"Paid"
            }).data('identityindex',count).appendTo(wrap);  


            wrap.appendTo('#unpaidList');    
            count++;         
        })//end of for each loop 
        $( "#unpaidList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
});

$(".myinput").click(function(){  
            var $this = $(this);          
            var index = $this.data('identityindex'); //undefined.  
            $.getJSON("http://s.mx/public/user/confirmbill/", {
                id: identity[index] 
                }, function(data) {
                    alert(data.status); 
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("error");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not enough code to tell what's going on.

Comment: I've edited and inserted the codes

Comment: You say the Paid submit doesn't do anything, do you have a click function somewhere? can you post it in your question

Comment: I have edited and added in the click function.